# Xamarin Form Labs Taking Video

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I am trying to use the takevideoasync from xamarin forms labs but it keeps crashing because of it, anyone have a quick example for it.

Thank you

Comment: when asking questions you should strive to make a quality question, not like a chatroom shout-out. in this case an example of what's crashing would improve the quality of the question by a lot

Comment: I just did mediapicker.TakeVideoAsync(){ Params } but it just crashes

Comment: You didn't just do that, you have code between your button click and the crash. And how does it crash? Error message? Stack trace? Environment targeted?

Comment: I might know why it isnt working, I was looking at the version and its v1.1.0 which is the latest one in nuget, but not the last xamarin forms labs. So if I download Xamarin Forms Labs from github how can i reference it in my project

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XLabs.Forms` nuget package instead of the `Xamarin.Forms.Labs` package. It is up to date with the [documentation provided on github](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs).